Can't modify inner content of ViewContainerRef, only adding tags after it in Angular
I have a few DIVs that may be marked with a directive special. That directive has certain logic that works. Now, I'd like to add a component within the DIV that is equiped with the directive.
<div special ...>Monkey</div>
<div regular ...>Donkey</div>

Following the docs on Using ViewContainerRef (suggested by this answer to a similar issue), I run the following in my directive.
@Directive({ selector: "[special]" })
export class SpecialDirective {

  private viewRef = inject(ViewContainerRef); ...
  constructor() {
    const icon = this.viewRef.createComponent(IconComponent);
  }

It works just as described in the docs: the created icon (corresponding to LeafContent) is placed in the DOM right after the DIV that's marked as special (corresponding to InnerItem). And this is precisely my problem: I want the icon to be a part of the inner HTML of the DIV that's governed by the directive.
I can't move the directive inwards for various reasons related to its logic. I've tried to access viewRef.element and inspected other fields and methods of it. To no avail. Setting index on the creation didn't help. The closest I got was detaching/inserting from the docs but it only let me manage the order of elements after my DIV, not within it.
I've seen this answer, but it's not going to help in my case because the alteration is happening after the user clicks on the DIV way past it's been created and placed in the view.
How can I alter the inside of the viewRef instance? Optimally, I'd like to remove some tags inside it as well besides amending the icon.

Since you want to insert the component without any child elements created, we can use createComponent standalone method, which takes the input of environment injector and we can use appendChild of Renderer2 to append this created element to the original elementRef.
export class InnerItem {
  constructor(
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private injector: Injector,
    private element: ElementRef,
    private envInjector: EnvironmentInjector,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}
  loadContent() {
    const componentRef = createComponent(LeafContent, {
      environmentInjector: this.envInjector,
    });
    this.renderer.appendChild(
      this.element.nativeElement,
      componentRef.location.nativeElement
    );
    componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
}

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  createComponent,
  ViewContainerRef,
  Injector,
  ElementRef,
  EnvironmentInjector,
  Renderer2,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'leaf-content',
  template: `
    <div>This is the leaf content</div>
  `,
})
export class LeafContent {}
@Component({
  selector: 'inner-item',
  template: `
    <button (click)="loadContent()">Load content</button>
  `,
})
export class InnerItem {
  constructor(
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private injector: Injector,
    private element: ElementRef,
    private envInjector: EnvironmentInjector,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}
  loadContent() {
    const componentRef = createComponent(LeafContent, {
      environmentInjector: this.envInjector,
    });
    this.renderer.appendChild(
      this.element.nativeElement,
      componentRef.location.nativeElement
    );
    componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'outer-container',
  imports: [InnerItem],
  template: `
    <p>This is the start of the outer container</p>
    <inner-item />
    <p>This is the end of the outer container</p>
  `,
})
export class OuterContainer {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [OuterContainer],
  template: `
    <outer-container/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

You can create a template reference variable #insertHere to explicitely specify where to insert the new component, we can use viewChild and specify the read property to get the ViewContainerRef which has the createComponent method.
@Component({
  selector: 'inner-item',
  template: `
    <button (click)="loadContent()">Load content</button>
    <ng-container #insertHere></ng-container>
  `,
})
export class InnerItem {
  insertHere = viewChild('insertHere', {
    read: ViewContainerRef,
  });
  loadContent() {
    this.insertHere()?.createComponent(LeafContent);
  }
}

Full Code:
import { Component, viewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'leaf-content',
  template: `
    This is the leaf content
  `,
})
export class LeafContent {}
@Component({
  selector: 'inner-item',
  template: `
    <button (click)="loadContent()">Load content</button>
    <ng-container #insertHere></ng-container>
  `,
})
export class InnerItem {
  insertHere = viewChild('insertHere', {
    read: ViewContainerRef,
  });
  loadContent() {
    this.insertHere()?.createComponent(LeafContent);
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'outer-container',
  imports: [InnerItem],
  template: `
    <p>This is the start of the outer container</p>
    <inner-item />
    <p>This is the end of the outer container</p>
  `,
})
export class OuterContainer {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [OuterContainer],
  template: `
    <outer-container/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Great answer, I appreciate it. There is a caveat, though. I can't rely on #here for a few reasons. In some cases there won't be anything inside the DIV before the click (and I'd prefer not to add <ng-container #here> due to extra complexity). Also, my click event comes not from a button but @HostListener in the directive so there's no template in the way the example is set up. Suggestions?

Just to investigate my options, I added the tag <ng-container #smack> inside the DIV and used private smack=viewChild("smack", { read: ViewContainerRef }); in the directive. It seems it comes in as undefined, so I sense that I'm obtaining it the wrong way (perhaps proper for a component but not a directive). I can't shake off the sensation that viewRef = inject(ViewContainerRef) gives me the container outside the DIV's template, only the directives (empty) template...

@KonradViltersten you have to check on ngAfterViewInit in my stackblitz it works.

@KonradViltersten updated my answer

Thanks. I can confirm it works for a component with a template. Unfortunately, in my use case, I'm doing that from a directive and (while a directive is indeed an component also), it won't get the content. Not sure why, because I expected it to be "there" but it's like it's not getting the DOM elements as a part of its elements (which can't be correct since they do list). I ended up in adding them "after the directive" and simply cheated with CSS moving the icon 20 pixies to the left. :(

I can't eliminate the possibility that I made a mistake and didn't realize it. However, I sense that there's something with how the directive interacts with the DOM of the element it's put on that differs. Everything is created when I click, yet, doing this.viewRef.clear() doesn't remove the existing elements, only the one that were added by the directive.

@KonradViltersten if you could replicate in a stackblitz on what you need on a new question I will check it
